# Adding a node to d3 network error (with fiddle example)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following issue:

I have small scenario -

> Adding three interlinked nodes to the graph,
>   removing one using a filter function,
>   adding it back again

Once I re-add the removed one it gets a bit scrambled and stays in the corner. I'm sure I'm missing setting function somewhere or something. Please have a look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/187/) and feel free to update it.

My add-node-back function

```
/* step 3: node B reappears with links */
    function step3() {
        var nB = {id: 'bbb'};

        nodes.push(nB);

        /* find exiting nodes for links */
        var nA = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === 'aaa'; })[0];
        var nC = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === 'ccc'; })[0];

        var lAB = {source: nA, target: nB};
        var lBC = {source: nB, target: nC};
        links.push(lAB);
        links.push(lBC);

        recalc();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're removing the nodes and links. The following lines create new `nodes` and `links` arrays, shadowing the previous definitions:

```
nodes = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id !== 'bbb'; });
links = links.filter(function(l) { return (l.source.id !== 'bbb' && l.target.id !== 'bbb'); });
```

The old, now shadowed definitions are still used by the force layout internally. That is, positions for the (removed) node bbb are still being updated. You just can't see that because the overwritten definitions are used in the `tick` handler function.

Now when you add a new node and new links, the data structures used internally by the force layout (the old `nodes` and `links`) aren't updated, only the new ones, used by the `tick` handler function are. This means that while the new node is drawn, the force layout doesn't know about it and hence doesn't compute coordinates for it.

There are two ways of fixing this. As pointed out in the other answer, you can simply reassign `nodes` (and also `links`!) to the force layout when they change:

```
 force.nodes(nodes);
 force.links(links);
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that you lose the internal state of the force layout. This matters less in your particular case where the layout is fairly settled when you make the changes, but if you do this just after starting when the forces are still quite strong, you may experience some "jumpiness".

The alternative is to modify the data structures that are used by the force layout directly instead of reassigning:

```
 function step2() {
   links.splice(0, 1);
   links.splice(1, 1);

   nodes.splice(1, 1);

   recalc();
 }
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/266/). I've hardcoded the indices of nodes and links to remove here to simplify, but you can obviously also compute them dynamically, as I've done in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7pm31tr3/).

Comment: Thanks for Your response and time taken. A very good read I must say. So the result Im aiming for is something like this: Have a slider that would filter out and delete nodes and its connections and reconnect left over nodes based on one of the node paramters - say its radius. Like a have in the following  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vlandham/yeQS2/191/) ; Ive tried to addopt your logic here but I cant seemt o recconect the 'left overs'. Would You mind taking a look at this ? Any suggestions Much appreciated

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything to reconnect nodes there. It sounds like you'd want to check, for nodes that have no connections left, which node is closest and add a new connection to that. Besides, that example has the same problem as yours here where the node and link variables are overwritten.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Although completely lost now Ill try to review  the code...Please excuse my ignorance, but is it efficient to do it in Your way, with splicing out the  nodes and the links, putting them in a variable say so I could re-add them if the filter is disabled ? not a (criticism just a question)

Comment: Altogether it may be more efficient to filter the array, but you won't notice unless you're dealing with many many nodes and links. It's kind of hard to tell because it's obviously related to what the force layout does internally as well when you modify vs reassign. I certainly wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: would it be possible to ask You to comment a bit more about 'reconnecting' nodes in my last fiddle ? 'When' it should be done in my process, feel free to add commentary in the fiddle itself

Comment: Well, like in the example you've posted here, you should make the modifications all together -- technically there's no need for that, but it keeps the code cleaner. So you would add the new connections after removing the old ones.

Comment: Hey, Ive tried to adapt Your example of filtering a node and its links with a bit of object orientated javascript. Could You please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/256/) and suggest what is the problem ? I have a simple 3 node diagram and then after a small delay im  calling a function to delete the middle node and the links around it. Once the arrays are modified I send the new elements to the recalc function to update the diagram. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You are only handling the enter selection, not the update or exit selections. Hence deleting nodes/links has no visible effect.

Comment: Would You mind updateting my diffle because to my ignorant newbie head it looks like im doing the same thing as You are in your previous example...#

Comment: I will investigate this thoroughly. If our paths ever cross - the beer is on me

Comment: Sorry to bother You again, but there's something wrong going on with Your example solution: Ive added one more link between L1 and L3, so when we remove L2 and its links the link between L1 and L3 should still be there but the outcome is L2 circle and link between L1 and invisible L3. Would You mind taking a look at it ? Ive logged the variables being passed into the recalc function and they seem to be right but the visual outcome is wrong... Heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/264/)

Comment: As soon as you change the nodes/links, you need to update the indices of things to remove as well. As I've said, I hardcoded them in my demo to keep things simple, but to use this in a real application you need to determine the index of the thing to remove dynamically.

Comment: Are they (indices) not removed properly in your latest [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/257/) . I am really missing a trick here , I removed the nodes and the links the same way as in your previous example. Thanks for Your patience

Comment: Hmm, I don't even see where you're setting the nodes/links for the force layout in your new fiddle.

Comment: Three functions : 1 (setData) and 2 (setLinksData) sets Links and 3 (setNodes) sets the nodes. Now if Im doing it wrong I am open to suggestions, but these are the functions that set the nodes/links initially. Hope that what You're asking/ looking for

Comment: Ok, you need to delete the links first and then the nodes: http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/265/

Comment: Any idea why is it that one needs to delete links first and then nodes ? Reason why Im asking is because if Your UI has a filter on node property, You would loop thorugh the nodes first to find which ones dont mach the criteria any more, delete them and then delete the matching links.

Comment: Well the links contain references to the nodes, so my guess is that D3 maintains them through that -- this isn't documented and I haven't looked at the source code though. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Im sorry but as much as I go though the code I dont think Your example works..Ive added several other nodes and still try to delete the same L3 node, but weird things happen, heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/273/) . It worked fine with the previous example with 3 nodes but not for this one.. Im sorry I didnt think this gonna be so difficult....

Comment: Ah right, you also need to match the links data properly in `.data()` -- http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/274/

Comment: Brilliant, thanks man. hopefully one day I could be helpful to You

Comment: Hey, So Ive pulled all the fiddles together into this: [grand filtering fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/296/) ,unfortunetely something doesnt work corectly and the wrong nodes are displayed. Ive debugged several times and Im sure the right nodes are filtered (based on the cSize property), and I think the right nodes are displayed its' text is wrong. I think the problem is in recalc functiona and with node enter and exit functions. Would You be able to take a look, couse I hit a dead end :/

Comment: You need to have a suitable key function for the nodes as well http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/297/ Didn't you have all of this in the original fiddle?

Comment: yeah I did, but it wasnt working with a slider. Now thanks to Your massive input I managed to achieve this result...in Your opinion what would be an efficient way of undo the filter action, what I mean is when filter is applied to filter nodes which have cSize < 2 , and then You slide back to 0 and want to recreate the previously filtered nodes ? Also my d3.js for dummies book is on the way....

Comment: Hmm, you could keep the removed links/nodes in an associative array indexed by the level so that you immediately have the nodes and links to add back when going to a specific level.

Comment: So id have a json-like structure of something like : Level 1 - {links} {nodes}, Level 2 {links} {nodes} and so on ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking of. You can of course also use any other data structure that you think would be appropriate.

Comment: HI, wanted Your opinion on something: see when the nodes are filtered and now there are some loose circles hanging, what would be a smart and efficient way of detecting that the circle has no connections and create a new connection to the nearest circle ?

Comment: Well should these circles still be there? Are they nodes that have no connections left? If so, what do the connections mean, and how would you determine what to connect it to?

Comment: Right, Ill put together a fiddle and come back to You on this, will be easier to see what Im trying to achieve here

Comment: You also might want to ask a new question -- this thread is getting a bit long (and not related to the original question anymore).

Answer (score 1):

I played with your fiddle. It appears that the newly added node has no x and y coordinates. That attributes are generated by the force layout. So I assigned the nodes to the force layout again. It fixes your problem. See here: [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/190/)

```
/* step 3: node B reappears with links */
function step3() {
    var nB = {id: 'bbb'};

    nodes.push(nB);

    /* find exiting nodes for links */
    var nA = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === 'aaa'; })[0];
    var nC = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === 'ccc'; })[0];

    var lAB = {source: nA, target: nB};
    var lBC = {source: nB, target: nC};
    links.push(lAB);
    links.push(lBC);

    // I added this line
    force.nodes(nodes);

    recalc();
}
```